# Java Reflection permission error

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, securitymanager

I'm trying to load a class via an URLClassLoader (well, it neither works with an normal class loader) and want them to not have any permission.

Therefore, i created my own security manager, which genereates a key on startup, which can only by requested once (in main thread). 
The security manager has 2 lists, the applicationThread, which will be granted any right and the temporaryList, which will be granted one right just once (it's about the reflection).

As it is very hard to descripe, i decided to upload the whole thing: *look at the link below*

Ok, coming back: I created a WatchDog thread, which checks if the thread doesn't take too much time.

When i now start to instance two classes from an URLClassLoader, I call exactly 30 methods without getting any errors, but on the 31st call, it tries to check Permissions for the following  but this is just happaning after the 30th call.

```
java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect),
```

Does anyone know what's going on there?

edit:
I had time to strip down the example. 
http://myxcode.at/securitymanager.zip
I found out, that the SecurityManager is not asked synchronous. Just run this small piece of code and have a look at the red lines.

If the red lines come in the very first line, just run the program again, you will find out that it seems a little bit uncontrolled.

The problem more or less is, that i need the security manager to be synchronized.
Here is my output for those who cannot face the error(bug?)
http://pastebin.com/E9yLRLif

edit2: maybe its about the console? maybe the console is too slow?

Comment: Boil your problem down to a small, concise, complete example and post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me the check occurs when `i=15`:

> checkPermission ( (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect) ) for Thread[main,5,main]

The reason for the delayed permission check is an `inflationThreshold` of the `ReflectionFactory` class which is used by the `invoke` method of [`NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/reflect/sun/reflect/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java.htm):

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object[] args)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    if (++numInvocations > ReflectionFactory.inflationThreshold()) {
        MethodAccessorImpl acc = (MethodAccessorImpl) new MethodAccessorGenerator()
                .generateMethod(method.getDeclaringClass(), method
                        .getName(), method.getParameterTypes(),
                        method.getReturnType(), method
                                .getExceptionTypes(), method
                                .getModifiers());
        parent.setDelegate(acc);
    }

    return invoke0(method, obj, args);
}
```

To disable the delay you could use Reflection API :)

```
Field hack = Class.forName("sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory").getDeclaredField("inflationThreshold");
hack.setAccessible(true);
hack.set(null, 0);
```

Comment: My JDK version is 1.6.0_23 btw